# Evoking more power than "Titan"

Tags: word-choice, terminology

[EVE Online](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eve_Online) is a multiplayer game that takes place across a fictional galaxy called New Eden. Players pilot spaceships and fight for territory in large collaborative corporations.

Here is a simplified list of the military-focused ship classes, going from smallest to largest:

- Frigate
- Destroyer
- Cruiser
- Battlecruiser
- Battleship
- Carrier
- Supercarrier
- Titan

The four variants of Titan are currently the largest vessels in the game. They usually require the efforts of hundreds of players to build and field. They are extremely valuable logistically and are able to carry an extravagant amount of  firepower. For many months after Titans were introduced to the game, the difficulty of fielding one kept their numbers in the single digits.

As of this posting, however, the number of surviving Titans is in the middle hundreds. It would appear that if it were the intention of [EVE's maintainers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCP_Games) to keep Titans rare (and I make no allegation that that is the case), then they have underestimated the growing cooperation and resourcefulness of New Eden's citizens.

Now then, here is the question:

If a warship class larger than the Titan were added to the game, what would it be called?

The word *Titan* comes pretty close to the ceiling in terms of evoking great power and strength. In Greek mythology, the Titans were a race of immortal giants descended from the gods Gaia and Uranus, themselves descended from Chaos, but neither *God* nor *Chaos* seem to be good names for ship classes. The first could be controversial; the second I think is more arguable (*Chaos Class Warship* has a nice ring to it), but I think that there are better alternatives.

For context, here is an alphabetical list of all ship classes currently in the game:

Assault Ship, Battlecruiser, Battleship, Black Ops, Capital Industrial, Carrier, Command, Covert Ops, Cruiser, Destroyer, Dreadnought, Electronic Attack, Exhumer, Freighter, Frigate, Heavy Assault, Heavy Interdictor, Industrial Command, Industrial, Interceptor, Interdictor, Jump Freighter, Logistics, Marauder, Mining Barge, Supercarrier (also called Mothership), Recon, Strategic Cruiser, Titan, Transport

For even more context, [this page](http://www.eve-wiki.net/index.php?title=Category%3aShip_Types) on EVE Wiki has more information about each ship class.

Comment: Based on the given formula, it would be called "Supertitan" :)

Comment: A little less detail would be helpful ;)

Comment: And Supertitan has a very Supertitanic ring to it.

Comment: Interesting though this question is, it doesn't seem constructive. All the answers are equally valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with "*Olympian*."

But not because of the Olympic fever these days.

In mythology, the Olympians are the younger generation of gods (including Zeus) who overthrew the Titans.

Aside from this, the word "*Olympian*" itself means, among other things:

- surpassing all others in scope and effect
- far beyond what is usual in magnitude or degree
- majestic or godlike in manner or bearing

all definitions from the [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/olympian)

Comment: This is a great idea. An Olympian would not necessarily have to be bigger than a Titan, but it would have some sort of super power that trumped that of a Titan.

Comment: +1 It should be noted, however, that Zeus, leader of the Olympians, was himself the son of Kronos, the leader of the Titans, and helped overthrew and imprison him. That said, Kronos overthrew his father, Uranus, as well.

Comment: More importantly, it preserves what seems to be a steady gradation up the different levels of names. The list is mostly made up of "earthbound" names, not really totally fictional. When it got to Titan is the only real time it became half-fanciful. So Olympian is a moderate continuation of that

Answer (score 4):

If *Supertitan* is not a good fit, I would recommend *Leviathan* or *Kraken* as they have ... naval connotations and also sound suitably awe-inspiring. *Behemoth* is also, IMO, a good fit.

Besides the above two you could try one of:

- *Uranus* (progenitor of the Titans),
- *Saturn* (of which Titan  is the largest moon),
- *Tartarus* (where the Titans were imprisoned)

Other generic synonyms of "titan" include *mammoth*, and *Goliath*.

Comment: Damn! Beat me to behemoth while I was typing the answer :) Oh, and Kraken's wonderful

Comment: @asymptotically I suspect that you read through all the detail in the question and I didn't ;)

Comment: Yes. I did find it rather interesting...

Comment: Of interest, one of the titans actually available in Eve is called a "Leviathan".

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: my answer is only valid within the universe of Eve Online, given the question's context.

Naming is hard, especially in game designs. The proper name needs to evoke the right emotional response, given the context of the universe players are put in.

You described perfectly why *Titan* is the right name for the current biggest ship class. [Killing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRlrFudaEs8) a "Titan" also yields a big sense of accomplishment in game for players, not just for those who finally manage to create and pilot one.

Each player race's Titan is appropriately named too. For example, Amarr, the super religious race has their Titan named Avatar, while the chaotic Minmatar's Titan is called Ragnarok.

Titans are demi-gods, so the next natural upgrade would be *God*. But as you said, it'd be controversial and it wouldn't have a nice ring to it.

I do not believe CCP, the maker of Eve Online, will add a "bigger(physical size)" ship class in the future. However, I think it's possible they will add another class that's equally epic, for a different fleet function.

My vote for a new super ship class is "Angel." It has a more supernatural ring to it than Titan. It's also versatile since an angel can be protective and destructive. Although it probably makes more sense if an Angel ship is a super [logistic](http://eve.wikia.com/wiki/Logistics_Ship) ship.

CCP doesn't follow Greek mythology for all of its naming conventions. There are a lot of famous biblical angels' names to choose from. For example, Amarr's Angel can be "Ariel" or "Appoloin."

In practice, I think *Angel* would work great in Eve player lingo too:

- "Angel fleet"
- "Goonfleet has slain two of A-'s Angels"
- "Fleet forming, need some Angel protection."

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Star Wars fan, so I'd call it 'Deathstar' or 'Eclipse'. Otherwise, aiming for the general population, I'd call it 'Behemoth' or 'the Goliath'.

Answer (score 1):

- [dreadnought](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreadnaught) - for 'fear nothing'. metioned in both the Star Wars and Star Trek universes.
- [juggernaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juggernaut) - an overwhelming or unstoppable force with lots of informal military uses. This has a very different etymology, from the Sanskrit Jagannātha "world-lord", one of Krishna's names

Answer (score 1):

I would say monolith would be fairly appropriate from a science fiction standpoint, referring to Arthur C Clark and his reference for monoliths being massive ships built by a completely unknown race of beings in 'A Space Odyssey'. Pretty much a ship from god.